# Invalid preceding regular expression with SED

Tags: json, regex, sed, replace, sh

I'm trying to replace a JSON value using SED regular expression. However, I'm experiencing the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 60: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

I have the following JSON object:

```json
{
  "profiles":{
    "http":{
      "applicationUrl":"http://localhost:5123"
    }
  }
}
```

I used regex101.com to create the following regular expression (PCRE2 - PHP >= 7.3):

```
(?<="applicationUrl": ")[^"]+(?=")
```

Here is a link with the regular expression and JSON object.
https://regex101.com/r/OwWRbc/1

I used regex101 code generator function to generate a SED command.

```
sed -E 's/(?<="applicationUrl": ")[^"]+(?=")/http:\/\/0.0.0.0:80/gm;t;d'
```

Here is a link to a SED validator showing the error:
https://sed.js.org/index.html?snippet=y7en7e

I'm expecting the JSON object to be updated as follows:

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:80"
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried to replace the forward slash with hash

```
sed -E 's#(?<="applicationUrl": ")[^"]+(?=")#http:\/\/0.0.0.0:80#gm;t;d'
```

Comment: First, *don't* use regex to parse JSON; use a real parser. Second, sed [doesn't support](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) lookarounds.

Comment: regex101 allowing you to create a sed command is just malpractice. **None** of their regex flavours apply to sed.

Comment: Also, you can used advanced regex in a stream processing mode with `perl -pe` but substitution command here in OP doesn't make much sense even with a stream processor that supports PCRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command:

```bash
sed -E 's/"applicationUrl": "[^"]+"/"applicationUrl": "http:\/\/0.0.0.0:80"/' input.json > output.json
```

reads the input JSON from `input.json` and writes the updated JSON to `output.json`. It replaces the value of `"applicationUrl"` with `http://0.0.0.0:80`.